# Uploading Webapp to CloudBees

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, cloudbees

I'm trying to upload my webapp and database to the [CloudBees](https://www.cloudbees.com/) but it seems that my database doesn't respond to the application. I followed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Nb-wm3lHIo) video to upload my database and [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKGXff0jjWw) video to upload my web application. But still doesn't work.

**Update I found this stacktrace:**

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at com.neu.als.thesis.utilities.DefaultValuesUtility.getQuestionsCount(DefaultValuesUtility.java:2069)
    at com.neu.als.thesis.utilities.DefaultValuesUtility.checkDataBase(DefaultValuesUtility.java:2240)
    at com.neu.als.thesis.web.controllers.DefaultController.index(DefaultController.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:432)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:946)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    ... 38 more
```

This is my app configuration in CloudBees:

[image]

And this is my database configuration in CloudBees:

[image]

my `web.xml`

```
<!-- Database resources -->
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/testd</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

My `context.xml`:

```
<Context>
  <Loader delegate="true" />
  <Resource name="jdbc/testd" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
    username="testus" password="password"
    url="ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
</Context>
```

my database connection class:

```
public final class DatabaseCommunication
{
    public static DatabaseCommunication getInstance()
    {
        return DatabaseCommunicationHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    /**
     * private declaration of dataSource variable to avoid instanciation
     */
    private DataSource dataSource;

    /**
     * @return returns data source instance
     */
    public synchronized DataSource getDataSource() throws NamingException
    {
        if( dataSource == null )
        {
            InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = ( DataSource ) cxt.lookup( "java:/comp/env/jdbc/testd" );
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    private static class DatabaseCommunicationHolder
    {
        /**
         * instanciates DatabaseCommunication
         */
        public static final DatabaseCommunication INSTANCE = new DatabaseCommunication();
    }
}
```

my setup in workbench:

[image]

The password is: `password`

I binded my database using this command:

In my local i was able to login to the accounts from my database. But I don't know why in CloudBees it doesn't. `bees app:bind -db testd -a demoproject -as testd`

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would prefer to do the binding with JNDI using this on your datasource.xml file

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/testdb" resource-ref="true"/>
```

You can try not to declare the datasource in the context.xml file. Instead of that, you will automatically inject it with the app:bind command through the CloudBees SDK. In this way you are sure that the datasource is correctly declared.

You should then delete this part of your context.xml file

```
<Resource name="jdbc/testd" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
username="testus" password="password"
url="ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
```

So, it should look like this:

```
    <Context>
      <Loader delegate="true" />
    </Context>
```

Comment: About the first option you gave where should I place that code and is there any changes I should make in my `web.xml`? And about the second option if I remove that code, where should I put the removed code? In my understanding that code defines the database. Sorry for this noob comment.

Comment: For the first option, you have an example on this ClickStart (https://github.com/CloudBees-community/spring-petclinic-clickstart/blob/master/src/main/resources/spring/datasource-config.xml#L42) Please, don't use Spring profiles (<beans profile="javaee" >) since you have to do more changes on CloudBees side if you use it.

For the second one, you don't have to put this code anywhere since CloudBees injects it automatically on the container when you launch the bees app:bind command.

Comment: Practical example: http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/10/step-by-step-guide-about-how-to-deploy.html I am coding a simple one, but I didn't finish it.

Comment: What about my `web.xml`? `<res-ref-name>jdbc/testd</res-ref-name>` should I also remove this?

Answer (score 0):

resource URL has to be a JDBC url `jdbc:mysql:ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/database`, not just server hostname